# Group by selects first occurence of field how can I get the last one?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

```
SELECT user_id, created FROM photo_comments GROUP BY user_id
```

returns

```
  user_id  created  
  1        2009-10-20 21:08:22 
  12       2009-10-20 21:45:00 
  16       2009-10-28 20:35:30
```

But that created date of 2009-10-20 for user id 1 is the first entry by user id 1.

How can I get the last entry by user id 1? (date should be 2009-11-02)

I'm trying to get the last entry by each user in order of most recent first.

Comment: Keep in mind, that group by "selects" an _unspecified_ occurence of the field, not the first. To be honest, it shouldn't select anything and the query should fail (it doesn't make any sense). But mysql for some reason allows such queries.

Comment: I'd love to have an aggregate function `some()` which picks a convenient value from a non-group-by column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinary SQL isn't supposed to allow that sort of query in the first place. In theory, you can only request a field that you named in a `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function of some other field. Here's how you'd build your modified query. (Then you can add other fields too on the first line.)

```
SELECT user_id, created
FROM photo_comments o
WHERE created =
    (SELECT MAX(created) 
    FROM photo_comments i
    WHERE o.user_id=i.user_id)
```

Comment: This is the best way, in my opinion.

Comment: mysql doesn't seem to care for your inner and outer. 'Error in your SQL syntax near "outer"'

Comment: `outer` and `inner` are keywords used with joins. I usually remember this little detail the first time I run the query and get the syntax error. I've fixed the answer now by renaming them `o` and `i`.

Comment: I added 'order by created DESC' to get the exact result I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
SELECT user_id, max(created) FROM photo_comments GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: In this version, you can't add other fields (like `photo_id` or `comment_id`) into the query and expect them to work sensibly.

Comment: just add `ORDER BY max(created) DESC` to the end

Answer (score 0):

does SELECT user_id, created FROM photo_comments order by created desc GROUP BY user_id

not work?

Comment: It orders the result set, so the example set I posted is listed in reverse order, still doesn't get the most recent entries.